# how to... a "plus" b to be converted in a "+" b

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

as the title says... how can i convert a word in an operator?
i have a script in AJAX

```
function calcPrice(elem,id,pret,i){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "data.php",
   data: "action=calcPrice&sign="+elem.className+"&id="+id+"&pret="+pret,
   success: function(msg){
    hcont = get_response_tag('tag1',msg);
    hcont2 = get_response_tag('tag2',msg);
     $(".price_val").html(hcont);  
     $(".nb_analize").html(hcont2);  

    if(elem.className=='plus'){ $("#p_row_"+i).removeClass("row_plus").addClass("row_minus"); elem.className = 'minus'; }
    else{  $("#p_row_"+i).removeClass("row_minus").addClass("row_plus"); elem.className = 'plus'; }
   }
});

}
```

which when i click on a plus (or minus) sign, it returns a value and the word "plus" or "minus".
in data.php i want to be able to make arithmetic based on the "plus" or "minus" words or convert those words in operators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($operator == "plus") {
    return $val1 + $val2;
} elseif($operator == "minus") {
    return $val1 - $val2;
}
```

IS the simplest example. In reality, you should probably send the request to a different endpoint based on which operation they click.

Comment: And to be sure, add `parseInt` to the elements.

Comment: Or a `parseFloat`, depending on the element types :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
if($val=="plus")
   return $a + $b;
else
   return $a - $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace here is ideal. You can use this function to replace patterns in a string with other patterns. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)